# SQL: How do I change my query to get the following result?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

For each customer-product pair, I need to calculate average sale of that product in each state.

Actual table ("sales" table):

```
cust  | prod  | state | quant
Bloom | Bread |  NY   | 1
Bloom | Butter|  NJ   | 2
.
.
.
```

My query:

```
SELECT cust, prod, state, AVG(quant)
from sales
group by cust, prod, state;
```

Result:

```
cust  | prod  | state | avg(quant)
Bloom | Bread |  NY   | 1
Bloom | Butter|  NJ   | 2
```

The result I want:

```
cust  | prod  |  NY  | NJ
Bloom | Bread |  1   | 2
```

Comment: Why don't you have `Butter` in the result you want?

Answer (score 1):

This is a pivot.

```
SELECT
    cust,
    prod,
    AVG(CASE WHEN state = 'NY' THEN quant END) AS 'NY',
    AVG(CASE WHEN state = 'NJ' THEN quant END) AS 'NJ'
FROM sales
GROUP BY cust, prod
```

If you can't hard-code the states like that, see [MySQL pivot row into dynamic number of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12004603/mysql-pivot-row-into-dynamic-number-of-columns) for how to implement a dynamic pivot in a stored procedure.